# Difference of DCMTK old and new versions

Tags: dicom

I couldn't load dicom images in my dicom viewer that using dcmtk old version.
The Dicom data that I have used have LUT Descriptor with Implicit VR Little Endian Transfer Syntax.

How can I resolve this issue?.Will the new version of dcmtk resolves this Issue?

Comment: Implicit VR needs a dictionary. Do you have the dictionary on the right path?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason a viewer will reject your DICOM DataSet is simply because it does not understand the SOP Class of your instance. For example Enhanced MR Image (Storage) are relatively new SOP Classes, thus an old viewer has no way of knowing that instances of this class contains an image.